# understand countVectorizer ngram returning data

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am totally new to python, and I have been trying to understand the return of fit_transform, my code is something like this

```
count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2), min_df=3)
counts = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(learningData)
```

I printed counts but the result was a list like that:
(4, 320)    1
  (15, 396) 1
  (17, 122) 1
  (19, 273) 1
  (20, 273) 1
I need to understand what does the (4 , 320) 1 represents. I found in the documentation :
X : array, [n_samples, n_features] ,, does that mean that for the first item in count_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), there was 4 samples of the learning data that contained it and repeated for 320 times? and what does the 1 represent?

Sorry I am totally new to this stuff.

Comment: Something like that. ngrams are assigned a unique identifier and then counted.

Comment: do u mean that the 4 is the unique ID and the 320 is the count?

Comment: Yes, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I guess the 4 is not a unique number,, I found some elements in counts like this (233, 453) 1 (233, 897) 1
The 233 is repeated 2 times with 2 different counts